# Autohotkey script - taskkill.exe error on Windows shutdown

Tags: autohotkey, taskkill

I am using lot of portable application locally on my laptop and if i leave some of them opened when i shutdown Windows it doesn't close them properly and some applications don't save their settings. I am trying to use taskkill option in a autohotkey script which will be executed on windows shutdown and will close properly opened portable application.

I am using this script:

```
#SingleInstance, force 
#Persistent 
DllCall("kernel32.dll\SetProcessShutdownParameters", UInt, 0x4FF, UInt, 0)
OnExit , closepgs 
return 
closepgs: 
If (A_ExitReason="Shutdown" or A_ExitReason="Logoff") 

{
Run, taskkill.exe /F /IM uTorrent.exe
}

ExitApp`
```

But when i shutdown Windows i receive this taskkill.exe error:

"Application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000142). Click on OK to terminate the application"

If i use the taskkill code outside the script like this it works fine:

```
^!Home:: 
Run, taskkill.exe /F /IM uTorrent.exe
```

But if i use it inside the script i receive taskkill.exe error.

Any idea why this error happening?

I have Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: I'm curious, how does `taskkill` ensure your programs exit properly?

Comment: I tested taskkill option from the command prompt and it is closing the applications properly. When Windows close them i receive crash message when i start them again and they loose their settings. Taskkill doesn't do that.

Comment: When you try to run taskkill the system is already being partially shutdown and running new programs like taskkill is not an option.

Comment: Yes, but the script tells Windows to execute first the commands in the script before anything else.

Comment: Have you tried using [Process, Close](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm) instead?

Comment: It works with Process, Close but i am wondering why doesn't work with taskkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Process, Close](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm) instead of `taskkill.exe`:

```
Process, Close, uTorrent.exe
```

It seems that as of Windows Vista and later, processes aren't allowed to spawn new processes during the shutdown phase. The only source a quick web search yielded was [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/db9daf83-7028-4836-9573-6446a2b164fd/windows-vista7-start-new-process-during-shutdown).
On a different note, using native functionality instead of calling programs is almost always preferable. Especially when using AHK, I recommend always looking for a built-in function to start with.